# About the positive class label

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, xgboost

I am applying machine learning `sklearn` models on a dataset, specifically `XGBClassifier`. However, this dataset was mistakenly labeling the positive class with `0` and the negative class with `1`.

My question is, should we tell the model during training which class has which label ? or we just rely on specifying that when computing the error metrics (accuracy, precision, recall, etc) ?

Example:

```
precision_score(y_true, y_pred, pos_label=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

model.fit is training, y_train is class or label or target of data train.

Comment: Thanks @Nisit, but I mean does the inner working algorithm require that it knows which label belongs to which class?